# Standardizing tab size when using a text area

Tags: html, angular, text, textarea

Currently I am using an HTML textarea attribute to take an input from a user and then taking that text and displaying it as formatted back to the user. However, it appears to handle tabs strangely. For example, when i try to input this

```
Wednesday       5:00 am – 5:30 am       
June 20         11:30 am – 1:30 pm      
                4:00 pm – 4:30 pm       
                6:00 am – 10:30 am      
                2:00 pm – 3:30 pm       

Thursday        5:30 am – 10:30 am      
June 21         2:30 pm – 4:30 pm       
                11:15 am – 1:15 pm
```

it comes out as this if i view to code in dev tools.

```
Wednesday       5:00 am – 5:30 am       
June 20         11:30 am – 1:30 pm      
                4:00 pm – 4:30 pm       
                6:00 am – 10:30 am      
                2:00 pm – 3:30 pm       

Thursday            5:30 am – 10:30 am      
June 21         2:30 pm – 4:30 pm       
                11:15 am – 1:15 pm
```

I have no idea why it is doing this. How should i go about fixing this problem. Or would something other than a text area be a better solution as it is very simple. Currently this is my approach because end users wish to be able to copy and paste from word. Thanks ahead of time.

Answer (score 0):

you can change the tab size property using CSS.
its default value is set to 8 char spaces and it can accept any positive integer.
foe example : 
the -moz an -o are required for firefox and opera,

```
textarea, pre{ tab-size:6 ;
-moz-tab-size:6 ;
-o-tab-size:  ;
-webkit-tab-size: 4; }
```

Comment: This wasnt exactly what i was looking for. I dont know if I said it clearly but the problem is when i actually pull the text out of the text area the tabs are different. So if i were to put it into a <pre> tag it would display different than how the user originally typed the text. I was wondering what was happening to the tab size there.